# For m white and m black balls, to show probability both ball has same colour is $\frac{m-1}{2m-1}$ when m random balls in bag A and remaining in bag B

Tags: probability

Question is that: From a total of $m$ white balls and $m$ black balls ($m>1$), $m$ balls are selected at random and put into a bag A, the remaining $m$ balls are put into bag B. A ball is then drawn randomly from each bag. Show that the probability that the two balls have the same colour is $\frac{m-1}{2m-1}$.

I have been working on this problem for one hour, but I have not clue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first ball is a certain color.

There are then $2m - 1$ remaining balls, each equally likely to be chosen as the second ball.  Of those, $m-1$ are the same color as the first ball.

Hence:  $P=\frac{m-1}{2m-1}$

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I understand now.

Comment: Maybe, then, an accept ($\checkmark$) is in order?